# Process.Start will not launch Acrobat c#

Tags: c#, acrobat

Process.Start will launch my PDF in the VS 2019 debugger but not from my app. 2 Acrobat processes show up in the Task Manager, but no window appears on the Desktop. If I assign the PDF to either Microsoft Edge or Chrome it works just fine. Any suggestions?

The code so far:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo s = new ProcessStartInfo(@"pathToMyPDF\My.pdf");
        //s.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat");
        s.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        p.StartInfo = s;
        p.Start();
```

Comment: _Any suggestions?_ Order matters. I recommend not setting _ProcessStartInfo_ property values using both `p` and `s`  and you'll eliminate your mistake.

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly. If I pare that code down to Process.Start(@"pathToMyPDF\My.pdf") I get the same result

Comment: PS I have Acrobat DC installed, not Reader

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because C# isn't magic.

That line modifies the `StartInfo` object on the process:

```
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
```

... and that line immediately overwrites it with the *other* `StartInfo` object you've created:

```
p.StartInfo = s;
```

Because yes, you have two different `StartInfo` object, `s` and `p.StartInfo`, and they're not kept magically kept in sync.

So that `p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true` code is basically wasted. Its execution doesn't matter, you've just undone it.

Really, just set your properties to that `StartInfo` object *before* you assign it to the process:

```
ProcessStartInfo s = new ProcessStartInfo(@"pathToMyPDF\My.pdf");
s.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
s.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo = s;
p.Start();
```

Or just don't create a second `StartInfo` and stick to the one on the process:

```
Process p = new Process(@"pathToMyPDF\My.pdf");
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.Start();
```

But don't mix and match, that's how you end up with problems.

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me the same result. I uninstalled Reader, and reinstalled but this time the 64 bits app. Now Reader processes won't even launch.

Comment: Looks like that not an issue with the code but with your system; if Reader isn't the associated app for `.pdf` files, then shell executing that file with the default verb won't launch Reader.

Comment: Reader was set as the default. But changing the Filestream code line to FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite); did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, what FileStream code?

Comment: Oh my bad Etienne sorry I omitted that. Originally the Filestream code was FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create)